# Sum all elements in a column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data in one column in Python dataframe.

```
1-2 3-4 8-9
4-5 6-2
3-1 4-2 1-4
```

The need is to sum all the data available in that column.

I tried to apply below logic but it's not working for list of list.

```
lst=[]
str='5-7 6-1 6-3'
str2 = str.split(' ')
for ele in str2:
    lst.append(ele.split('-'))
print(lst)
sum(lst)
```

Can anyone please let me know the simplest method ?

My expected result should be:

```
27
17
15
```

Comment: `sum((int(x) for x in '5-7 6-1 6-3'.replace("-", " ").split(" ")))`

Comment: Don't use `str` as variable name

Answer (score 3):

I think we can do a split

```
df.col.str.split(' |-').map(lambda x : sum(int(y) for y in x))
Out[149]: 
0    27
1    17
2    15
Name: col, dtype: int64
```

Or

```
pd.DataFrame(df.col.str.split(' |-').tolist()).astype(float).sum(1)
Out[156]: 
0    27.0
1    17.0
2    15.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Those solutions are actually the fastest (the latter only on big dataframes) ;)

Comment: @mozway thanks man ~

Answer (score 1):

Using `pd.Series.str.extractall`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col":['1-2 3-4 8-9', '4-5 6-2', '3-1 4-2 1-4']})

print (df["col"].str.extractall("(\d+)")[0].astype(int).groupby(level=0).sum())

0    27
1    17
2    15
Name: 0, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.str.extractall` and `sum` on a level:

```
df['data'].str.extractall('(\d+)').astype(int).sum(level=0)
```

Output:

```
    0
0  27
1  17
2  15
```

Answer (score 0):

A for loop works fine here, and should be performant, since we are dealing with strings:

Using @HenryYik's sample data:

```py
df.assign(sum_ = [sum(int(n) for n in ent 
                      if n.isdigit()) 
                  for ent in df.col])
Out[1329]: 
           col  sum_
0  1-2 3-4 8-9    27
1      4-5 6-2    17
2  3-1 4-2 1-4    15
```

I hazard that it will be faster taking it out and working within Python, before returning back to the pandas dataframe.